# how does it work in react routes property

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i usually saw routes code in react like this

```
  <div className='App'>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
    </BrowserRouter>
```

but i saw some code in github  was

```
const App = () => {
  const routing = useRoutes(routes);

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyles />
      {routing}
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};
```

and

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    element: <DashboardLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: 'account', element: <Account /> },
      { path: 'customers', element: <CustomerList /> },
      { path: 'dashboard', element: <Dashboard /> },
      { path: 'products', element: <ProductList /> },
      { path: 'settings', element: <Settings /> },
      { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> }
    ]
  },
```

i can't understand some property "element" and "children"

how can this possible?
and what should i call this? (i can't find document or something..)

(sorry for my english skill )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's great that we can have all our routes in one place. However, this could be hard to manage in the future when we have tens or hundreds of routes in our application. One way we can keep things a bit cleaner is by using child routes. Child routes are just routes that are displayed inside another route. This means that there can be more routes inside a component that is rendered by another route.

React Routes are easy to use, Simply your App.js file look like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Cms from './Cms';
    
const App = () => (
<div className="app-routes">
<Route path="/" component={Cms} />
</div>
);
export default App;
```

Check this out for more details: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_router.htm